# Can a subscriber go through the same Journey more than once?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

### Can a subscriber go through the same Journey multiple times?

Assume I have a Journey with a simple trigger, something like:

```
Optional_Field IsNotNull
```

The Journey sends a simple email: "Thank you for filling out Optional_Field"

Once a user goes through the Journey, receives their email, and exits the Journey, will they be picked up by it again the next day?

Or does Journey Builder keep track of the users who have gone through a Journey, and block them from entering it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the statement in my previous answer:

> Once a Contact has entered an Interaction, they cannot enter an Interaction more than once, even if the Contact has already exited the Interaction. If you create a new version of the Interaction and publish it, then the same rule applies; if the Contact has entered any previous version of the Interaction, then they will not enter the new version.

There have been some new features added to Journey Builder (on 25 Jan 2015) **that change this previous answer**.

### 1. Contact Entry Mode

A new Contact Entry Mode has been added to the Interaction Canvas which enables you to define whether a Contact can enter an Interaction once (across all Interaction versions), or multiple times. Refer to the screenshot below for setting this mode.

[image: Contact Entry Mode]

This can also be defined when [creating an Interaction](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/postCreateInteraction.html) using the Fuel REST API by including one of the following name/value pairs in the WDF payload:

```
"entryMode": "MultipleEntries"
"entryMode": "SingleEntryAcrossAllVersions"
```

If you do not define an `entryMode` when creating an Interaction, then the Interaction will use `SingleEntryAcrossAllVersions` by default.

### 2. Date-Based Triggers

A new 'Date-Based' Trigger has been added to Journey Builder that enables date-based Attributes from the Contact model to determine an entry criteria for the Interaction.

A threshold defines the number of days, weeks or months and start time that the Contact should be admitted into the Interaction, before or after the selected Attribute date.

A re-entry criteria defines whether a Contact can re-enter the Interaction (either yearly, monthly or none). [Refer to the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/triggers/selecting_a_trigger/#DateBasedTrigger) for further details.

[image: date based trigger]

Comment: To clarify my original answer, it turns out that Contacts have never been prevented from entering an Interaction more than once. In previous Journey Builder releases, Contacts were only prevented from being in the same version of an Interaction simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I can partly answer this question. Assuming that you are firing an Event using Automation Studio, then the following answer applies:

> Once a Contact has entered an Interaction, they cannot enter an Interaction more than once, even if the Contact has already exited the Interaction. If you create a new version of the Interaction and publish it, then the same rule applies; if the Contact has entered any previous version of the Interaction, then they will not enter the new version.

While this suits the majority of Interactions, it doesn't really work for recurring Interactions; for example, for Birthday or Anniversary Interactions where you want to send a Contact an email every year. You would need to set up duplicate recurring activities every 365 days to ensure that the Contact keeps on moving through the Interaction.

Having said that, I have yet to clarify whether this behavior still applies when firing an Event using the [contactEvents](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/contactEvents.html) API method. Consider this:

1. You have an Interaction that sends out order confirmation emails
2. When an order is created in an eCommerce platform, the `contactEvents` method is used to serialize the order data into an 'Orders' Data Extension, which has a cardinal relationship with a customer Data Extension (configured when creating a New Event in Contact Builder).
3. When the `contactEvents` method is used, it will fire an Event for a defined Trigger and serialize data into the Orders Data Extension.

You would assume that in this instance, Contacts would be able to enter an Interaction more than once — that is, for each order they make, they receive a 'Send Email' Activity.

I will test this for you and let you know how I get on. I can't actually get the `contactEvents` method working correctly at the moment, but when I do, I will confirm the behavior.